# Serialize YAML document from Perl data structure

Tags: perl, yaml

I'm attempting to print out a YAML document from a data structure, in particular, an array of hashes, which is what I think YAML::dump returns. Here's the Perl code I'm using to build a YAML document and serialize it.

```
my @tagobj_header_table =
{
core => {
    type => $tagobj_type,
    size => $tagobj_size,
    blob => $tagobj_blob,
},
text => {
     lines => {
     {
         offset => 0,
         length => 1
     },
     {
         offset => 1,
         length => 5,
     },
     {
         offset => 6,
         length => 7,
     },
     {
         offset => 13,
         length => 13,
     },
     {
         offset => 26,
         length => 1,
     }
     }
  }
};

my $dumper = YAML::Dumper->new;
my $tagobj_contents = $dumper->dump(@tagobj_header_table);
print $tagobj_contents;
```

Here's what I want the YAML document to look like, with some Perl string substitutions.

```
---
core:
    type: $tagobj_type
    size: $tagobj_size
    blob: $tagobj_blob
text:
    lines:
        - offset: 0
          length: 1
        - offset: 1
          length: 5
        - offset: 6
          length: 7
        - offset: 13
          length: 13
        - offset: 26
          length: 1
```

The following is the output of the console.

```
---
core:
    blob: build\content\objects\36d80951814b5f08c7ba34cd7a5459b4c212ee6200ce247ac2a13d24b2fc0d57
    size: 31
    type: blob/text
text:
    lines:
        HASH(0x4d1b840):
            length: 13
            offset: 13
        HASH(0x4d1df38):
            length: 5
            offset: 1
        HASH(0x4d1eee8): ~
```

Comment: .text.lines is a hash (`{}`) in your data structure, but what are the keys? what are the values? You clearly want an array (`[]`) there instead.

Comment: Make it an answer so I can accept it @mwp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Perl data structure you are using doesn't correspond to the YAML data that you require. It is only by chance that it compiles at all, and you must have seen a warning

> Odd number of elements in anonymous hash

when you execute your code. Please don't ignore warnings, especially when asking for help with your code

In YAML, the `lines` element is an array, whereas your Perl data has it as a hash. You need to replace the braces `{ ... }` with square brackets `[...]`

I also suggest that you avoid `YAML::Dump`, which is a miconceived hack of the `YAML::Tiny` module. `YAML::XS` is the preferred Perl implementation of YAML, and is a binding for the excellent `libyaml` library

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a YAML problem; `lines` should map to an arrayref, not a hashref:

```
text => {
     lines => { # this is an hashref, so
     {
         offset => 0,
         length => 1
     }, # this is a hash key, and gets stringified: "HASH(0x4d1df38)"
     {
         offset => 1,
         length => 5,
     }, # and this is a hash value
     {
         offset => 6,
         length => 7,
     }, # this is a key, also stringified: "HASH(0x4d1b840)"
     {
         offset => 13,
         length => 13,
     }, # and this is a value...
     {
         offset => 26,
         length => 1,
     }
     }
  }
};
```